# Slope and side-slope of vineyard rows

Tags: line, slope

I have a question about interpreting the slope and side-slope of vineyard rows using a line vector layer and a DEM.

I am trying to calculate the slope along the row (split into 2 meter lengths) as well as the side-slope (or the slope at 90 degrees to the line).

Ultimately I would like the output to be slope and side slope attributes in the vineyard row line vector layer so I can identify any areas which are too steep for tractors.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use the Slope tool. In ArcGIS Pro Spatial Analyst-> Surface Toolset_> Slope. It will classify a slope for the pixels in the DEM.

Reclassify (Raster Calculator) the Slope file to your requirements. Lets say that the tractor can only work safely on slopes of less than 10 degrees.

Slope < 10 reclassifies to "1."
Slope > = 10 reclassifies to "0."

Select all reclassified pixels with a value of "0" and export to a new raster.

Convert that raster to a polygon shapefile.

Intersect the polygon with your vineyard line shapefile.
The resulting intersection will be unsafe areas to operate a tractor.

Side note-I'm not 100% sure if this will work for your situation, but I ran a similar workflow recently for a project I was working on.